# Sending POST params to CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, http-post

When using `FormHelper::input('field')` in a `View`, it will create a `<input name="data[Model][field]" />` tag.

What if I want to sent `POST` params from a `JAVA` client or something. Should my `POST` params be called "data[Model][field]" or just "field"? example:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[Model][field]"
```

vs

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"
```

Comment: Question is not clear do you want post params names to be named just fields or asking for correct way?

Comment: asking for the correct way

Comment: All depends how you code your controller.

Comment: If you are CakePHP then Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[Model][field]" is the correct way because it will eliminate data manipulation at Model level

Answer (score 1):

Nopes, I think as per the web standard it will be access by name of input box, cakephp create some magic rules for that, but at the end it follow the web standard :), so as per my knowledge it will be access by name.

**Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"**

Cheers!

Saran

Answer (score 1):

data[Model][field] auto generating only when you crating form with CakePHP methods. For example if you send POST data from Java client I suggest you just:
var_dump($this->request->data);
Then you will see how you need to use your income data.